# Compare equivalency of two objects of arbitrary types

Tags: c#

I have a function which takes two generic object inputs, converts the second to the first and then compares the two.

The function:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    object parameterCast = System.Convert.ChangeType(parameter, value.GetType());

    return parameterCast.Equals(value);
}
```

I think there are a couple of problems with this that I'm not sure how to solve, however.

The first is, what if the parameter can't be cast to value?

Secondly, do I need to check if each of the objects is null? And if so, how?

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice for modifying this function?

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There are no generics in this function.

Comment: And looking at the MSDN documentation of [System.Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttf5d382%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also helps. It throws an InvalidCastException if the cast is not supported.

Comment: @TimRogers Yeah, sorry. I wasn't really thinking when I wrote that, I meant generic in the sense that it's just a general object and I don't know the type.

Comment: I think here "generic" means of type `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a separate *method*<sup>1</sup>. Would you provide a few examples of how you intend to use the method?

As for modifying the function, your example code doesn't use the `targetType` or `culture` arguments. Also, the name of your function is confusing as its return value is the result of an `Equals` method.

Instead of using the method, you might be able to use `parameter == (ParameterTargetType)value`, but there's no way to convert an object to an arbitrary type or class so you'll need to either implement some way to do so, or use a `try ... catch ...` statement to handle the possible cast exceptions.

Oh, yeah, to check whether an object is null just use `object == null`. With an `if` statement, you could write:

```
if (value == null)
{
    // Do something if the 'value' object is null.
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Generally, functions in C# are called methods. They always (?) are when the function is a member of a class.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I'll give it a go now. The format kind of has to be kept the same because of the way the whole code is structured (calling them converters threw me a bit too). I was never clear on the distinction between methods and functions though, good to know what I should be using.

Answer (score 2):

The most *accurate* way to check if `value` is null is

```
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value)) {
    // value is null
    ...
  }
```

Other popular ways

```
  // == operartor can be implemented explicitly
  if (value == null) {...}

  // Equals method could be overriden
  if (Object.Equals(null, value)) {...}
```

could potentially be *incorrect*, since `Equals` method or/and `== operator` can be *overriden/redeclared*.

Comment: For `value == null` which `==` is used?

Comment: "public static Boolean operator == (ValueClass left, ValueClass right) {...}" where ValueClass is a value's class, if this operator is declared

Comment: So is `null == value` equivalent to your "most accurate way"?

Comment: No, in this case "public static Boolean operator == (ValueClass left, ValueClass right) {...}" could be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the references are pointed to the same thing, then check if either are null, you can return what ever you would like. after it you can cast then compare if these both pass.

```
if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
{
    return true;
}
if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) || System.Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
{
    return false;
}
```

However i would think about actually using a Generic function.  something like this should work.  If `as TData` fails the object will be null if it isn't return the equals operation.

```
public object Convert<TData>(TData value, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        where TData : class
    {
        TData convertedObject = parameter as TData;
        if (convertedObject == null)
            return false;
        else
            return value == convertedObject;
    }
```

it is untested though.